# How to get credentials for getting user email after OAUTH with Google API Python Client

Tags: python, google-api

I'm trying to get user's email after OAUTH.

I have already found this code:

```
def get_user_info(credentials):
  """Send a request to the UserInfo API to retrieve the user's information.

  Args:
    credentials: oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials instance to authorize the
                 request.
  Returns:
    User information as a dict.
  """
  user_info_service = build(
      serviceName='oauth2', version='v2',
      http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))
  user_info = None
  try:
    user_info = user_info_service.userinfo().get().execute()
  except errors.HttpError, e:
    logging.error('An error occurred: %s', e)
  if user_info and user_info.get('id'):
    return user_info
  else:
    raise NoUserIdException()
```

But I am not understanding what kinda "credentials" I need to pass in the function. I have already tried to pass Credentials from google.oauth2.credentials and credentials as file (.json), didn't work out. I would be happy if someone would help me with this code or give other solution.

Comment: go though the people api.  make sure you request email scope when you authorize the user.

Answer (score 0):

Credentials in this case will come from a combination of the info you got from the Google Dev portal and the http redirect to Google for the user to give your app permission the required permissions.

Build the credentials object separately and then pass it through to "build()" as the argument for credentials.

Building the [credentials object](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/google.oauth2.credentials.html) will look something like this:

```
credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
    token=token,
    refresh_token=refresh_token,
    id_token=id_token,
    token_uri=token_uri,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret,
    default_scopes=default_scopes
)
```

For more on this check out the Google OAuth 2.0 documentation, it specifies code snippets specifically for Python.

edit:

Have you tried:

```
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    'client_secrets.json',
    scopes=['openid', 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'])

flow.run_local_server()
credentials = flow.credentials

service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

# Optionally, view the email address of the authenticated user.
user_info_service = build('oauth2', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
user_info = user_info_service.userinfo().get().execute()
print(user_info['email'])
```

This is from the docs. Should allow you to build the credentials object using your JSON file.

Comment: Thanks, but can I get all these args from secret key (that "credentials.json")?